# l accidentally permanently deleted a Draft. There's any way I can recover it?

Tags: posts, draft, customization

I recently started a blog and I was about to finish my second Post. 
I was cleaning up some stuff and decided to empty my Trash. I wasn't paying much attention to it because I wasn't expecting my Draft to be there. I accidentally deleted it. There's any way I can at least visualize it and somehow retype it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you've emptied the Trash you can't recover anything from it (and note after 30 days in trash, a post will be permanently deleted.)

If you have database backups, you can restore a draft from the `wp_posts` table (look for records with `post_status = "draft"` and grab the `post_content` field.

https://en.support.wordpress.com/deleted-posts-and-pages/

Answer (score 0):

At least in Chrome and Firefox you can enter `about:cache` and start digging there. With some luck you might still find something.

Unfortunately I can't give you a more detailed instruction as I've never done this before myself. Also if you plan to follow that path you are not too likely to be helped here on WPSE as this isn't a WordPress issue now any more.